# Formula para generar precio público

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo convertir el siguiente String en una Operación Matemática en PHP?

```
(PB+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%
```

Este string lo recibo desde una Base de Datos y ocupo que al final se sustituya el valor de PB (Supongamos que es 154), entonces la formula debería quedar:

```
(154+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%
```

Hasta aquí he llegado porque no logro saber como puedo indicarle a php que 25% lo interperte como un porcentaje y no como un string.

---

**Actualización**

Para ser un poco mas claro, la formula deberá ser de la siguiente forma:

```
$subtotal = (154+(154*.25)+(154*.05)+(154*.06));
$total = $subtotal+($subtotal*.05)+($subtotal*.1);
```

Ahora ahora yo intentente basandome en la formula;

*(154+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%*

```
$concepto = "(154+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%";
echo eval("$concepto");
```

Pero me arroja un error: **Parse error: syntax error; unexpected ')'**, naturalmente por el paréntesis que contiene le variable `$concepto`

Comment: ¿25% de qué exactamente?¿De PB?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, exacto 25% de 154. Actualizo la pregunta para ser mas claro.

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿PB es siempre PB o puede ser otra cadena?

Comment: PB siempre será PB...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sabiendo que PB siempre será PB, una cosa que puedes hacer es crear tu propia función que procese la cadena de la siguiente manera:

1. Cambie todos los `%` por `*(PB/100)`
2. Cambie todos los `PB` por el valor pasado
3. Evalúe la cadena
4. Guarde/devuelva el valor obtenido

El resultado sería algo como esto:

```
$p  = "(PB+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%";

function calculaPB($cadena, $pb) {
    $cadena = str_replace("%", "*(PB/100)", $cadena);
    $cadena = str_ireplace("PB", $pb, $cadena);
    eval('$cadena = ' . $cadena . ";");
    return $cadena;
}

echo calculaPB($p, 100);
```

---

Edición: He hecho un cambio para que preprocese los paréntesis primero. Lo hago con expresiones regulares que detectan el paréntesis (si hay alguno) en el que está el PB, procesa ese paréntesis y entonces actualiza la cadena y el valor de PB, y así en un bucle hasta que ya no queden paréntesis.

Así sería el código (aunque se debería poder limpiar un poco porque se repite la misma porción de código dentro y fuera del bucle):

```
function calculaPB2($cadena, $pb) {
    // procesamos PB mientras haya parentesis
    while (preg_match("/\(([PB][^()]+)\)/", $cadena, $matches)) {
        $aux = str_replace("%", "*(PB/100)", $matches[0]);
        $aux = str_ireplace("PB", $pb, $aux);
        eval ('$pb = ' . $aux . ';');
        $cadena = str_replace($matches[0], "PB", $cadena);
    }

    // una vez eliminados todos los paréntesis, ya sólo queda hacer una última
    $aux = str_replace("%", "*(PB/100)", $cadena);
    $aux = str_ireplace("PB", $pb, $aux);
    eval('$valor = ' . $aux . ";");

    // devolvemos el valor
    return $valor;
}

echo calculaPB2("(PB+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10%", 154);
```

Que para 154 devuelve un valor de 240.856 que parece correcto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la voy a probar ahora mismo y agregaré mis comentarios.

Comment: Alvaro, sabes no me ha resultado correctamente, la función me retorna esto: (pb+25*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100)+10*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100))+3*(pb/100)+4*(pb/100) he puesto pb para no colocar la cantidad, pero el problema es cuando despues de; (pb+25*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100)+10*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100)) sigue poniendo PB en;  +3*(pb/100)+4*(pb/100), aqui ya no deberia ser PB, deberia ser el resultado de toda la operacion que esta dentro de los parentesis. Me explico.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco ¿puede ser porque estás pasando `pb` en minúsculas y yo tengo `PB` en mayúsculas? Prueba a cambiar `str_replace` por `str_ireplace` (para que el cambio sea independiente de mayúsculas/minúsculas). Voy a editar la respuesta con el nuevo código.

Comment: No, el pb en minusculas solo fue pleno ejemplo en este Comentario.. lo que refiero es que despues de los (), no deberia existir PB. osea no deberia existir (......)+3*(PB/100)+4*(PB/100). El 3% y el 4% es el porcentaje de la operacion que se realizo dentro de los (). Ejemplo; (pb+25*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100)+10*(pb/100)+5*(pb/100)) + 3% + 4%.

Comment: Entonces hay que parsear la cadena y la cosa deja de ser tan sencilla. ¿Puede haber múltiples niveles de paréntesis?

Comment: Claro alvaro puede haber múltiples niveles de paréntesis...

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Otra pregunta: ¿Puede haber más de un PB en la cadena?

Comment: No, el PB es solo único. No vuelve a aparecer en otro lugar.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Podrías limpiarla un poco y que se quede mejor, pero creo que ahora sí captura la idea que buscabas

Comment: maestro, es lo que buscaba... ha quedado de lujo. gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a tu pregunta:

El problema, independientemente de que la operación sea correcta o no, es separar todos los números y operadores necesarios y detectar que operación se quiere realizar.

Si es una fórmula estática, puedes obtener el valor único variable y la procesas insertando dicho valor en una formula con idéntico cálculo.

Pero si la fórmula puede ser variable en contenido, o se preven cambios a futuro, lo mejor es automatizar la evaluación y el cálculo correspondiente.

> ¿Cómo puedo convertir el siguiente String en una Operación Matemática en PHP?

Buscando encontré una clase que puede ayudar, según he observado, separa los elementos y construye la fórmula a partir de un string dado.

La clase en GitHub: [EvalMath](https://github.com/Itangalo/evalmath.class.php)

Y una [respuesta en SO en Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14999744/6272471) que hace uso de la clase.

```
$m = new EvalMath;
$m->suppress_errors = true;

// set the value of x
$m->evaluate('x = 3');
var_dump($m->evaluate('y = (x > 5)'));
```

Quizás pueda servir de ayuda.

**EDITO**

La he probado con `(154+(154*.25)+(154*.05)+(154*.06))` y funciona correctamente contrastando el resultado con calculadora.

Comment: Oscar muchas gracias por tu respuesta voy a probar cada solución que me dieron al igual que la tuya y te comento si me ha servido.

Comment: Hola @OscarR oye no he tenido oportunidad de ver tu respuesta, pero me queda una duda con respecto a todo lo que se ha eventuado, sabes si esta clase si soporte algo similar  a : (154+25%+5%+6%)+5%+10% tomando en cuenta la profundidad de los parentesis...

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco la fórmula tal cual la pones no lo soporta, si la profundidad de paréntesis. No obstante tampoco daría el resultado deseado de aceptarla. Tal cual la recibes se interpreta así: `(154+25%+5%...` es lo mismo que: `(154*1.25*1.05...` y va calculando e incrementando sobre la operación anterior. Cuando lo que realmente estás buscado es: `(154*1.25+(154*0.05)+...` que va calculando cada operación sobre un valor fijo y después lo suma. De poder interpretar la fórmula tal como viene de la base de datos daría un resultado erróneo.